# Make different Mathematica notebooks stop talking to each other

Tags: scripting

So basically I am working in two completely different notebooks. But, if I define something in one notebook, it will overwrite the same definition in my other document.

Somehow these files talk to each other. I want to be able to use the same name for different functions in different documents. Any ideas on how I can get the different documents to stop sync with each other?

Comment: I usually use different kernels for each notebook.

Comment: I think the simplest way is to start 2 Mathematica processes.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

> Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to This Notebook

[image]